# Neural Network learning to hover. Time delay?

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, torch

I'm diving into machine learning with neural networks and after reading some theory and looking into torch I'd now like to use a neural network to learn how much thrust a simple helicopter with a unknown model needs to generate to hover in place at a reference height.

I have a control background and I know that one usually wouldn't use neural networks or machine learning in general for this, however I thought this would be a good first task to do.

I figured that all I needed was a simple linear regression (in NN form) to learn the function that maps measured height to thrust (producing exactly the right amount of thrust to counteract gravity at reference height).

But this already seems a bit complicated to do. Assume that I have a simple dynamics simulator and that I'm given a height measurement every `fs` Hz. I do a forward pass on my model (see model code below) to calculate the thrust for the model. So far so good. However the effect will not be instantly visible, so using the current measurement to also perform a forward and backward pass on the loss function seems the wrong thing to do. Or is it?

So ultimately the question is: Can I solve the stated problem with the simple linear regression that I proposed or do I need something more complex to capture the "response time" of the model.

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'

local model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Linear(1, 1)) -- Simple linear regression with one input (measured height) and one output (thrust)

local criterion = nn.MSECriterion -- Simple mean squared error loss function.

heigh_ref = 1

function height_measurement_callback(height_meas)
    local thrust = model:forward(height_meas)

    criterion:forward(height_meas, heigh_ref) -- ??
    local grad = criterion:backward(height_meas, heigh_ref) -- ??
    model:backward(height_meas, grad) -- ??

    return thrust
end
```

Comment: Could you state the problem clearly? Less torch api calls and more info on what are inputs and how are they obtained, please.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand what you want. There isn't alot to clarify. Imaginge the callback being called by the host simulation environment with given frequency, providing a scalar measurement of the height of the helicopter and the return value is used as thrust. EDIT: Maybe you are confused about the absense of a training data set. I want the NN to learn directly from the output of the simulation.

Comment: The problem here is not about neural network, it is about understanding what do you expect it to do. Do you specify a particular thrust value for model and then run simulation tracking vehicle height? Or do you set a particular height and want program to alter thrust until it gets to hover at the designated height?

Comment: the second version. I want it to learn while the simulation is running continously.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: Set a particular height `h_desired` and have the program find corresponding thrust value. Assuming that there is one to one correspondence between the thrust and the height.

---

Rational solution: Minimize the `h_desired - h_current` by adjusting the thrust based on current difference between heights.

---

Machine learning solution: Have a bunch of measurements, run regression on them, try to use obtained model to predict new values, verify prediction, add actual values to the training set.

Assuming that the "forward path of the NN" is the calculation of deviations of predicted values from the actual ones: `delta_i=(y_predicted_i - y_observed_i)`, and the backward pass is the calculation of `k` and `b` in `y_predicted_i = k * x_i + b`, there's no need to separate them. It is actually difficult to me to think of anything reasonable to do in-between those operations.

Now using the updated model you predict new value of thrust, that should bring you to desired height, and then you make new measurement, you set new thrust value and see which height value it corresponds to. Obviously, you must wait till the helicopter stops moving before putting new thrust-height pair to the training data and doing next iteration of linear regression. This is not so much about "Neural network model" but rather about the data acquisition process. You should not confuse them together. You must always finish measurement before adding the data to the experience of the model.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifing this, however I think this answer doesn't quite capture my scenario, maybe I have been not detailed enough after all. Main problem is that you assume a one-to-one relationship between height and thrust, however it is not physically accurate to think of thrust x producing height y indepently of the current height. For each model, there will be a thrust such that the model is hovering at steady height, any thrust above or below that will create an acceleration instead of a new fixed height.

Comment: So technically if say the helicopter is at height a with thrust x, there are many possible ways to get from a to target height b. i guess I need another constraint, like minimize the time to reach target height?

Comment: Well, then what exactly do you intend to linearly regress? It is then the second paragraph in my answer is the way to go. If you want some fancy restraints, there are various articles on trajectory optimizations. No one ever thought of calling them the machine learning, however.

Comment: And, if you use [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aeroforces.svg) (similar to engine torque or power),  there is indeed correspondence between the thrust and the maximum height a helicopter can achieve with it.

Comment: I like to define thrust as the z-component of the force vector generated by the rotor. Even if you use the definition you posted, this definition merely imposes a limitation on how much thrust an engine can achieve (i.e. overcome drag). However lift is merely a function of the speed (linear or angular) of the blade, therefore not merely the amount of upwards acceleration is limited, but not height (assuming constant air pressure).

Comment: Technically there are infinitely many "correct" functions that the NN could regress to achieve the behaviour I desire (i.e. accelerate upwards when below the setpoint and accelerate downwards (by providing less thrust than necessary to counteract gravity) when above the setpoint). By choosing linear regression, I seek the function (of arbitrary gradient) that will generate exactly m*g thrust upwards when at the setpoint height. Therefore ideally, in the simulation the helicopter will eventually converge to the setpoint.

Comment: The additional "fancy" constraint were just an idea for me to reduce the arbitrary gradient of the solution to a unique solution.

Comment: Well, in real life assumption of the constant air pressure is wrong. From your explanations it seemed that you wanted the height ceiling with for helicopter operating at a given power.